# Reclaiming missing Revolut SWIFT transfer

Tags: money-transfer, european-union, swift

I've sent a SWIFT transfer from my Revolut account to a Polish bank account (owned by my father). After sending it, I was asked for additional details (presumably because the amount was relatively large). I provided those details (also double checked the recipient data), but the money never arrived to the recipient.

I reached out to Revolut customer support to figure out what happened to the money, and either unblock it, or send it back. However, after 6 months of talking to the support and being assured that "a relevant team is looking into it" without any results, I'm not convinced that they're going to ever give me back my money, especially since they're refusing to tell me what is actually happening.

Whenever I ask them what they're doing, whether they're doing a SWIFT trace, etc., they just give me the same generic response about "the relevant team". Also, the recipient bank told me to have Revolut deal with it.

What other recourse do I have to recover the money that is currently stuck in limbo?

Comment: Try to find out if you have a banking ombudsman in your jurisdiction. They may be able to help you with this.

Comment: random guess (IANAL): lawsuit time?